# JSHint plugin for Spring ToolSuite

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs-directive, jshint, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite IDE and i am looking for a JShint plugin for STS.Can anyone please let me know if you have come across any of the plugin in your project  requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STS is based on Eclipse, so you can go to the Eclipse Marketplace (even directly from within STS) and install regular Eclipse plugins into it. I would search for a JSHint plugin in that marketplace: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/

Comment: Thanks for the response.this is helpful :)